# SQLAlchemy map columns with spaces/ brackets in them to class attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mapping

How do I go about mapping columns from a table with class attributes. Some of the column names I am working with are table.[An example] and table.

Comment: You can specify a [different name](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#defining-attributes) for your attribute than the actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

@Jasonca
 There are two ways to resolve this. You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686249/1055704

1. When defining the table you would need to specify an alias with the key parameter

   ```
   table_name = Table( 'table)name', metadata, Column('SQL Column',Integer, key='sql_column'))
   ```
2. When creating the entity class you may specify a field name

   ```
   class Employee(Base):
       emp_name = Column("employee name", String)
   ```