# SQLAlchemy column name with space

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to filter a table on a column that contain spaces.

```
...
events = database_session.query(table)
events.filter(table.column with space == 'xvalue')   < -- I want to do that
...
```

There is for sure a simple way of doing that, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve this.

1. When defining the table you would need to specify an alias with the key parameter

```py
t_table_name = Table(
    'tablename',
    metadata,
    Column('SQL Column', Integer, key='sql_column')
)
```

2. Define the ORM class as

```py
class Employee(Base):
    emp_name = Column("employee name", String)
```